# How do I select from a SQL table with knex where row values are consecutive?

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

Say I have a database representing a library, and a table that stores the words in each book. Let's call the table "books" and say it has rows like this:

```
| book_name | word_in_book | word    |
|-----------|--------------|---------|
| Moby Dick | 1            | call    |
| Moby Dick | 2            | me      |
| Moby Dick | 3            | ishmael |
```

If I had a sequence of words that I wanted to find (that could be any number of words long), what SQL query could I run to return a list of `book_name`s that have that sequence of words where `word_in_book` is consecutive? For example, if I had the list ["call", "me", "ishmael"], the query would return "Moby Dick" since the book has that sequence of words in order. However, running it with ["call", "me", "ahab"] would not return that book because those words are not a subarray of the words in the book (so it should only return books with a matching subarray, **not** a matching subsequence).

I'm using [knex](http://knexjs.org/) with Express to build my SQL statements. My hunch is that I'll need to use knex to loop over the array of words to be searched for and add something onto my query object for each word, but I have no idea how to do that.

This is all I can think of so far:

```js
const knex = require("knex")({
  // Connection details here ...
});
const words = ["call", "me", "ishmael"];

let query = knex("books");
words.forEach(word => {
  query = ??? // Not sure how to build my query
});
```

The real database I'm using at work is pretty similar to this. The difference is there are thousands of books but each book doesn't have that many words (only a few hundred at most). The problem is, selecting all the content of each book and checking all the words with JavaScript would be pretty slow, so I'd like knex/SQL to do as much of the work as possible. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the query you want to do is something similar to :

```
SELECT books.book_name
From books
join books bw2 on bw2.book_name = books.book_name AND bw2.word_in_book = books.word_in_book + 1 AND bw2.word = 'me'
join books bw3 on bw3.book_name = books.book_name AND bw3.word_in_book = books.word_in_book + 2 AND bw3.word = 'ishmael' 
where books.word = 'call'
Group by books.book_name -- avoid having twice the same book.
```

As you can see you will have to join the same table several times, to find the next word. There could be a simpler query using user defined variables on some database, but knex does not seems to support it (could not read from it in the link you have given).

For this query to work not too slow, you should add a composite index on three columns (you did not provide your backing database, but if you are using mysql / mariadb it would be :

```
ALTER TABLE books ADD INDEX (word, book_name, word_in_book);
```

). Indexing your table will be important for this query.
[SQL Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9bf192c150468421d54c5e6123540179)

Next, using knex to create the query :

```
const words = ["call", "me", "ishmael"];

var query = knex("books").select({
    book_name_searched: 'books.book_name'
}).where('books.word', words[0]);
words.forEach( (word, index) => {
    if (index < 1) return;
    query = query.join('books as bw' + index, function() {
        this.on('bw' + index + '.book_name', '=', 'books.book_name')
           .andOn(knex.raw('bw' + index + '.word = \'' + words[index] + '\''))
           .andOn(knex.raw('bw' + index + '.word_in_book = books.word_in_book + ' + index))
    })
});

query.groupBy('books.book_name');

query.toString();
// "select `books`.`book_name` as `book_name_searched` from `books` inner join `books` as `bw1` on `bw1`.`book_name` = `books`.`book_name` and bw1.word = 'me' and bw1.word_in_book = books.word_in_book + 1 inner join `books` as `bw2` on `bw2`.`book_name` = `books`.`book_name` and bw2.word = 'ishmael' and bw2.word_in_book = books.word_in_book + 2 where `books`.`word` = 'call' group by `books`.`book_name`"
```

I did not run it against a real database with knex, but the query string seems good. Tell me if it does not work, I hope you will at least have ideas to write your query.

Comment: That makes sense - and yes, I am using MySQL, sorry I forgot to specify. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's a good solution by hsibboni.
A simpler query that you could construct is:

```
SELECT
book_name 
FROM books
WHERE
(word='call' and word_in_book=1) OR --word_in_book=index
(word='me' and word_in_book=2) OR
(word='ishmael' and word_in_book=3) OR
GROUP BY book_name
HAVING count(1)=3 --words.count
```

Comment: The only thing is I'm not sure what the `word_in_book` value would be - all I know is that the characters I'm searching for have to be consecutive.